# Problem with interface builder and Objective-C custom class _TtC12

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I was thinking of creating a small application with Objective-C, but when I compile the storyboard, it complains that it can't find a custom class in the target. Usually, class names start with `_TtC` when Interface Builder tries to find Swift classes in the project. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

You can see my error here:

[image: screenshot]

```
2023-06-20 19:21:42.388111+0400 BatterySense[9298:2055160] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC12BatterySense20MainMenuController.m in Interface Builder file.
2023-06-20 19:21:42.390137+0400 BatterySense[9298:2055160] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC12BatterySense20MainMenuController.m in Interface Builder file.
2023-06-20 19:21:42.391632+0400 BatterySense[9298:2055160] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC12BatterySense12MainMenuView in Interface Builder file.
[_TtC12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpjO6.jpg)
```

I checked that my classes are correctly set up for Objective-С, re-added classes to the project, and rebuilt project, but still have this issue.

Comment: Check that the `MainMenuController.m` is inside your target. Uncheck and recheck "Inherits Module from Target", rewrite manually the class name, and let autocomplete help you.